# How to archive comments from a YouTube video page for myself?

Tags: youtube, comments, archiving

Looking for a faster way to save comments under a YouTube video rather than manually expanding the page, collapsing the sub-comments and copy paste in some text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the YouTube Data API, specifically the [`commentThreads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads) function.